# Variant implementation in C++

Tags: c++, variant-type

I've been fiddling with templates and compile time stuff i implemented a variant container and wanted some opinions and recommendations this is just a learning exercise, a couple template classes not included here are `tl_type_at` which gives the type in a typelist at a given index; and `tl_index_of` which gives the index of the first occurrence of the given type in a typelist:

```
template <size_t Index, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct variant_deleter
{
    variant_deleter<Index + 1, Ts...> next;
    void operator()(size_t HeldIndex, void* HeldPtr) const
    {
        if(Index == HeldIndex)
            delete static_cast<T*>(HeldPtr);
        else
            next(HeldIndex, HeldPtr);
    }
};

template <size_t Index, typename T>
struct variant_deleter<Index, T>
{
    void operator()(size_t HeldIndex, void* HeldPtr) const
    {
        if(Index == HeldIndex)
            delete static_cast<T*>(HeldPtr);
        }
};

struct bad_variant_access {};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct variant
{
    typedef typelist<T, Ts...> types;

    variant()
        : union_(new T())
        , held_(0)
    {}
    template <typename I>
    variant(I Init)
        : union_(new typename tl_type_at< tl_index_of<I, types>::index, types >::type())
        , held_(tl_index_of<I, types>::index)
    {}
    ~variant()
    { variant<T, Ts...>::deleter_(held_, union_); }

    template <typename P>
    variant<T, Ts...>& operator=(const P& rhs)
    {
        union_ = new(union_) P(rhs);
        held_ = tl_index_of<P, types>::index;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename G>
    G& get()
    {
        if(held_ == tl_index_of<G, types>::index)
            return *static_cast<G*>(union_);
        else
            throw bad_variant_access {};
    }
private:
    void* union_;
    size_t held_;
    static const variant_deleter<0, T, Ts...> deleter_;
};
```

Comment: As explained in the [help/on-topic], please do not modify your code, because it invalidates existing answers. If you want your updated code to be reviewed you can post a new question for it.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- the assignment operator doesn't call the destructor of the existing data, before setting a new value (results in UB, likely a resource leak).
- by default you do not instantiate an empty variant with the default constructor; the first type in the union may not even be default-constructible.
- `bad_variant_access` should probably inherit from a standard exception (std::runtime_error or std::logic_error are common as base classes).